# How to use AWK to query a file loaded with mapfile

Tags: awk, memory, performance

I am using awk on Ubuntu to corelate references between two log files (In.log and Out.log).
It is working as expected, but went the size of the Out.log increase (~K lines), the processing time increase also !
So I was wondering, to reduce disk access, if I can load this Out.log file in memory once before the loop, using the MAPFILE command or something similar, but I do not see useful examples.
Any suggestions?

**IN.LOG:**

```
2016-10-20 19:20:00,IN,DEU00000000159560100
2016-10-22 19:22:20,IN,DEU00000000159560511
2016-10-24 19:24:20,IN,DEU00000000159560382
2016-10-26 19:26:20,IN,DEU00000000159560609
2016-10-28 19:28:20,IN,DEU00000000159560809
```

**OUT.LOG:**

```
2016-10-20 19:20:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560100
2016-10-21 19:21:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560510
2016-10-22 19:22:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560511
2016-10-23 19:23:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560381
2016-10-24 19:24:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560382
2016-10-25 19:25:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560195
2016-10-26 19:26:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560609
2016-10-27 19:27:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560433
2016-10-28 19:28:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560809
2016-10-29 19:29:30,OUT,DEU00000000159560694
```

**Current script:**

```
cat IN.LOG | while read -r Line
do
    Reference=$(cut -f3 -d',' <<< $Line)
    TimeStampIn=$(cut -f1 -d',' <<< $Line)
    TimeStampOut=$(awk -F',' -v Ref=$Reference '$3==Ref {print $1; exit} ' OUT.LOG)
    echo "$Reference,$TimeStampIn,$TimeStampOut"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one `awk` command like this:

```
awk -v reflog=OUT.LOG '
    BEGIN{
      FS=OFS=",";
      while((getline <reflog) > 0) refs[$3]=$1;
      close(reflog)
    }{
      print $3,$1,refs[$3] ? refs[$3] : "not found"
    }' IN.LOG
```

Or using `join` which is exactly made for use cases like this:

```
join -t, -j 3 -o 0,1.1,2.1 -a 1 -e "not found" \
  <(sort -t, -k3 IN.LOG) <(sort -t, -k3 OUT.LOG) \
  | sort -t, -k2
```

Note, `join` needs sorted input files (by "join column"). That's why we sort before both log files by reference column and afterwards we sort the output again by date.

**Both soutions behave differently** regarding non-unique references in OUT.LOG. `awk` would ignore duplicate refs in OUT.LOG (last one wins) but `join` would print all matches. Moreover if you add `-a 2` to the `join` command then it would print *all* un-pairable lines.

Comment: Many thanks, i just needs to implement with the rest of the business, both solution are quite fast!

Comment: Hi, it works perfectly ! Performance a very good 
Many thx
What I still try to do is to output as 4th element, the difference in second between the two timestamps.

Comment: @user3489729 To add a date diff column  I would use another `awk` (`mktime`) command on the current output, like `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";}{a=$2; b=$3; gsub("[:-]"," ",a); gsub("[:-]"," ",b); a=mktime(a); b=mktime(b); diff= (a>0 && b>0) ? b-a : "-"; print $0,diff}'`

Comment: Hi, indeed, it was I read from several proposals, but mktime is not defined in   AWK, I will probably need to use gawk, but this is not yet available on the server.

Comment: @user3489729 Maybe you should post the timediff thing as a separate question.